# How to check If an object is empty?

Tags: php, object

How can I check if a PHP object is empty (i.e. has no properties)? The built-in `empty()` does not work on objects according the doc:

```
5.0.0 Objects with no properties are no longer considered empty.
```

Answer (score 7):

### ReflectionClass::getProperties

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getproperties.php

```
class A {
    public    $p1 = 1;
    protected $p2 = 2;
    private   $p3 = 3;
}

$a = new A();
$a->newProp = '1';
$ref = new ReflectionClass($a);
$props = $ref->getProperties();

// now you can use $props with empty
echo empty($props);

print_r($props);

/* output:

Array
(
    [0] => ReflectionProperty Object
        (
            [name] => p1
            [class] => A
        )

    [1] => ReflectionProperty Object
        (
            [name] => p2
            [class] => A
        )

    [2] => ReflectionProperty Object
        (
            [name] => p3
            [class] => A
        )

)

*/
```

Note that `newProp` is not returned in list.

### get_object_vars

http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php

Using `get_object_vars` will return `newProp`, but the protected and private members will not be returned.

---

So, depending on your needs, a combination of reflection and get_object_vars may be warranted.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the solution:;

```
$reflect = new ReflectionClass($theclass);
$properties = $reflect->getProperties();

if(empty($properties)) {
    //Empty Object
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you elaborate this with some code? I don't get what you're trying to accomplish.

You could anyhow call a function on the object like this:

```
public function IsEmpty()
{
    return ($this->prop1 == null && $this->prop2 == null && $this->prop3 == null);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe (not entirely sure) that you can override the isset function for objects.
In the class, you can provide an implemention of `__isset()` and have it return accordingly to which properties are set.

Try reading this:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members